# How does my choice affect the ending?

Tags: far-cry-3

Spoiler alert, please don't hover over this is if you haven't finished the game yet

> At the end of Far Cry 3, there is a choice to join Citra, or choose your friends. Does anything change depending on which choice you make? I chose to go with my friends, but I want to know how it changes if I had decided to join Citra.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you kill your friends:

> A sex scene with Citra follows. When it's over, she believes that she is now pregnant with Jason's child. Then she kills Jason with the dagger to give him the honor of "a warriors death".

When you refuse:

> Citra is disappointed. Dennis is upset with Jason defying Citra and tries to stab him, but he accidentally kills Citra instead. The game ends with Jason monologuing about how the events of the game changed him.

Comment: Darn it! I made the wrong decision

Comment: @SSHThis You went for your friends? I did that too :(

Answer (score 4):

The difference is who dies and who lives, along with ending cinematic that show it.

if you save your friends Citra dies.
If you go with Citra, your friends die.

First part of the video shows what happen when you pick Citra, it then continues with what happen if you pick your friends

[Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tC9zHnUCwjY)

Comment: I guess I'm weird because I cant avoid a getting a smirk when I think, what if she does not conceive?

Answer (score 0):

You will kill your friends if you choose Citra. It depends on you: your family or Citra?

Comment: The main reason I asked was because I didn't want to go through the whole story again, to see what would happen :/ especially since I'm at like 81% of the achievements.